# Why set sender to nil when sending NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsnotificationcenter

I see a lot of people, including textbooks, sending notification as

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someNotification" object:nil userInfo:data];
```

Why would they prefer that form instead of the following?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someNotification" object:self userInfo:data];
```

Does specifying the sender affect the receiver in some negative way? I imagine specifying the sender would be best practice.

Comment: I would say setting `sender` is best practise as this can always be ignored by subscribers, however it's necessary for subscribers who want notifications from that specific instance.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `sender` to `nil`, it implies you are posting a "general" notification, and that can be representative for all the objects that post this notification. Think of it from the subscriber end; when you request notifications from a certain object, it scopes it to only those posted by that object. If you set `object` to `nil` while subscribing, you'll receive all the `someNotification`s regardless of object.

Comment: But that's the thing: If I specify the sender, then a subscriber who wishes to specify nil can still do so while one who wishes to specify the sender can also still do so. Therefore the better design is to specify the sender. I was hoping there was a more esoteric reason such as optimization for time or space complexity.

Comment: Since `nil` is still an object type, a method has no way of confirming that there is an object passed unless it evaluates it and throws an exception or returns an error. So on this note, welcome to AppKit from 1999!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any object as the object of a notification, but the convention is that the object is the "thing that is doing the notifying". If you pass nil to object then it is not going to harm anything but obeserver will not identifying the current object. Self is required when you are posting multiple notification, in that case observer need to know the current object.